# dotenv production mode in nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dotenv

Hi I want to switch my app to production mode and I use windows and Visual Studio Code,I use expressjs in backend and creat-react-app in frontend.Below is the data tree
[image]

Below is the package.json and file where dotenv comes from:

[image]

[image]
And I want to switch it into production mode in backend,below is my backend data tree:

[image]

I add script in server.js:

[image]

And I also to change `NODE_ENV=development` into `NODE_ENV=production` in `.env`file.
At last I input `npm start` like below:
[image]

And I get into localhost:5000,but failed.Anyone could advice?

Comment: where does dotenv come into play?

Comment: You need to require dotenv in your server.js and load the config: `require("dotenv").config();` (by default, invoking config will load the `.env` at the root directory; if you want to load a specific path see the [dotenv config method documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#config)). In addition, you should separate your env files. One for development and one for production, similar to the [CRA recommendation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used).

Comment: @MattCarlotta OP already imported it (show in the 3rd image)

Comment: I add file where dotenv come into play.Even I try built a new `.env.development` file and set `NODE_ENV=production`,it does not work still.

Comment: Can you try `const result = dotenv.config();` and `console.log(result.error)` to check for errors?

Comment: See you again thanks.Output is `undefined`

Comment: @juexu Unable to replicate your issue. Running the `server` script produces the expected [result](https://i.imgur.com/7Ec05i2.png). On a related note, `.env` files shouldn't be commited to git control. To remove it, add it to your `.gitignore` and take a look at  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-can-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitign) to remove it from git cache.

Comment: @MattCarlotta,thanks for your strive.The result I want is that user can get into a e-commence shop main page while user input `http://localhost:5000/` in the browser.But nothing happened now.Thanks your tips on `gitignore`.It would be open until this question closed.Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove`app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.send('API is running') })` after`app.use(express.json())`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to set the path to the `.env` file explicitly (https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path).
Something like `.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../.env") })`

Comment: Hi @justpen,thanks.I change dotenv.config() into dotenv.config({ path: './.env' }),but still not working.